# Upper bound on risk in structural risk minimization

Tags: machine-learning

In pg. 64-65 of "Foundations of Machine Leaning (2nd Ed.)" by Mohri et al. there is a discussion about structural risk minimization.

The hypothesis class $\mathcal H$ is decomposed into a union of hypothesis classes $\mathcal H=\cup_{k\geq 1}\mathcal H_k$. The bound at the start of page 65 says that for all $h\in\mathcal H_k$, with probability $\geq 1-\delta$ over an iid sample of $m$ elements $S$,
$$
R(h)\leq\hat R_S(h)+\mathfrak R_m(\mathcal H_k)+\sqrt{\frac{\log k}{m}}+\sqrt{\frac{\log 2/\delta}{2m}}
$$
where $R$ denotes risk (expected 0-1 loss), $\hat R_S(h)$ denotes empirical risk, and $\mathfrak R_m$ is the Rademacher complexity.

I am confused why there is a dependence on $k$ in the bound. As per the discussions in the textbook, we do not even assume the $\mathcal H_k$ are nested. Hence to me, the value of $k$ is totally arbitrary and serves only as an index; I can for example permute all the $\mathcal H_k$ around arbitrarily and hence reindex the $k$ arbitrarily. This doesn't seem right, so clearly I must be missing something about what $k$ means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You (slightly) misquoted the learning bound on page 65 : the actual bound is given by (emphasis mine)

> $$R(h)\leq\hat R_S(h)+\mathfrak R_m(\mathcal H_{\color{red}{k(h)}})+\sqrt{\frac{\log \color{red}{k}}{m}}+\sqrt{\frac{\log 2/\delta}{2m}} $$

The crucial thing that this notation highlights is that **$k$ depends on the hypothesis $h$**. More specifically, the author defines $k(h)$ as follows

> For any $h\in\mathcal H$, we will denote by $\mathcal H_{k(h)} $ the least complex hypothesis set among the $\mathcal H_k$s which contain $h$.

The idea is that, although the hypotheses sets $\mathcal H_k$ may not be nested, the indices $k$ are a *measure of complexity* for each $\mathcal H_k$, hence picking a more complex hypothesis will hurt the generalization error accordingly. Figure 4.4 in the book and following discussion should make it clearer.